# Show that distributions of linear combinations of two variables determine couple law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X=(X_{1},X_{2})$ and $Y=(Y_{1},Y_{2})$ be two $\mathbb{R}^{2}$-valued variables. Show that if $aX_{1}+bX_{2}$ has same distribution as $aY_{1}+bY_{2}$ for all real numbers $a,b$ then $X$ has same distribution as $Y$.

I know this can be made to follow by the fact that knowledge of  the characteristic function $v\mapsto\mathbb{E}(\exp(i\langle v, X \rangle))$ determines the distribution of $X$. However I don't know how to prove that (and I know it is tedious), so I was wondering if it could be made to follow from the fact that $t\mapsto \mathbb{E}(\exp(itX_{1}))$ determines $X_{1}$, or even better if it is possible to prove this fact without characteristic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is a special case of the so-called [Cramer-Wold device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $n$-dimensional random vectors such that, for each $s\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $s^TX \stackrel{dist}= s^TY $. We wish to show that this implies $X\stackrel{dist}=Y$. Now, [Levy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem) guarantees that
$$
\phi_{X}(s) = \phi_{Y}(s),\ \forall\ s\in\mathbb{R}^n \implies X\stackrel{dist}=Y\,.
$$ 
So, we need only show that $\phi_{X}(s) = \phi_{Y}(s)$. But, this follows, because each pair $s^TX,\ s^TY$ are univariate identically distributed random variabes (so their characteristic functions agree), therefore

> $$
> \phi_{X}(s) = \mathbb E\left[e^{is^TX}\right] = \phi_{s^TX}(1) = \phi_{s^TY}(1) = \mathbb E\left[e^{is^TX}\right] = \phi_{Y}(s)\,.
> $$

According to Billingsley, at the time of the print of the second edition, "This result...seems to require Fourier methods - no elementary proof is known". I am aware of [Walther's 1997 proof](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B7Ch-c2G21MC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=cramer%20wold%20device%20proof%20without%20using%20fourier&source=bl&ots=Tn4xo_z8R-&sig=57l3PgSE5DN7TGJmr6YWbqjDY58&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OAzxVNyBBorlUu7vgKAN&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=cramer%20wold%20without%20Fourier%20transforms&f=false) which does not use Fourier methods. Whether it is "elementary" is another matter entirely :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, especially the reference to Walter's proof ! I don't see the connection between Levy's continuity theorem and the fact that $\mathbb{P}_{X}\mapsto \varphi_{X}$ is injective but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: $\phi_X = \phi_Y \implies X \stackrel{d}{=} Y$ has *nothing* to do with Lévy's continuity theorem; this is simply the fact that distributions are uniquely determined by their characteristic function. (And, actually the OP stated that he doesn't want to use this uniqueness-result to prove the statement.)

Comment: @saz, Hi, for the trivial sequence $X_n = X,\ \forall\ n$, is the observation that $\phi_{Y}(t) = \phi_X(t) = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\phi_{X_n}(t),\ \forall\ t \implies Y  \stackrel{d}{=} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_{n}\stackrel{d}{=} X$ justified by the theorem? I am willing to be set straight. Admittedly, it would have been easier to simply just appeal directly to the uniqueness property of characteristic functions.

Comment: @saz, And, concerning what the OP does or does not want, I think my answer was holistic: I highlight the general *well-known* result (which no one had done before my response), I provide a short proof and references to different approaches to proving the result. Please feel free to post an alternative proof; we are a community after all.